# Как создать уникальное имя (хеш) для сохранения фотографии

Tags: php, хеширование, md5

Как создать уникальное имя (хеш) для сохранения фотографии ? У меня вот так-

```
$format_avatar = explode(".", $_FILES['image']['name']);
$name_photo  = md5(uniqid(rand(),1)) .'.'. $format_avatar[1];
```

Может лучше id пользователя и номер фотографии хешировать.

```
$format_avatar = explode(".", $_FILES['image']['name']);
$name_photo  = md5($id . ++$countPhoto .'.'. $format_avatar[1];
```

Comment: Что именно значит «уникальное»? Уникальное в каких пределах? Если вы упоминаете слово «хеш»: как часто разрешены (и разрешены ли вообще) коллизии?

Comment: что-бы в одной папке и в БД не повторялись.

Comment: **Гарантировано** не повторялись? Или всё же лишь с какой-то вероятностью?

Comment: гарантировано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гарантировано это счётчик, а потолка какого-нибудь bigint Вы вряд ли достигнете в обозримом будущем (да и необозримом тоже)